# How to parse a json array that contains multiple datatypes?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json array:

```
var a = [{"results":[{"id":"25","name":"John","age":"46"},{"id":"41","name":"Sonny","age":"31"}],"count":2,"total":14}];
```

It contains an array called "results" and two other variables with numerical values, count and total.

How can i get each of the values of "results", "count" and "total" from the above array ?

I tried: console.log(a.count);

But it says undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ***[execute your code](http://jsfiddle.net/JtMgZ/)*** will cause `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

There is an invalid character after `age` between `"age"‌​:"31"`.

[**Remove that**](http://jsfiddle.net/JtMgZ/1/), then `a` is an array, so you get the first element by `a[0]`,

then

get the count by `a[0].count`

get the results by `a[0].results`

Answer (score 2):

To load results:

```
console.log(a[0].results);
```

To load count:

```
console.log(a[0].count);
```

To load total:

```
console.log(a[0].total);
```

Comment: P.S results is an object, so you will have to load whatever element of result you need like so:  console.log("results id: " + a[0].results[0].id);